# Combine a function with a variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to combine a function with a variable to create a single statement. I've come up with this:

```
<?php

function vars(){

    $x = 0;
    $id = 1;
    $event_id = 2;
    $doc4 = 'Additional';
    $doc6 = 'This';
    $doc7 = 'That';

    while ($x < 100){

    if(isset(${"doc" . $x})){
        echo '("' . $id . '", "' . $event_id . '", "' . ${"doc" . $x} . '"), ';
}
    $x++;
}

}

echo 'INSERT INTO event_docs (id, event_id, doc_type, d) VALUES ' . vars();
```

Which returns this:

```
("1", "2", "Additional"), ("1", "2", "This"), ("1", "2", "That"), INSERT INTO event_docs (id, event_id, doc_type, d) VALUES
```

When I want it to return this:

```
INSERT INTO event_docs (id, event_id, doc_type, d) VALUES ("1", "2", "Additional"), ("1", "2", "This"), ("1", "2", "That")
```

I've tried moving the combing it as two variables i.e:

```
echo $insert . vars();
```

But I keep getting the same result of the vars(); function appearing at the very top. I then tried putting a variable at the top of the page and including this but made no difference.

I'm presuming I'm missing something about calling a function in an echo function?

Comment: Separate data modification from presentation. Build your value as a string and append strings, and only print out the result variable-

Comment: You should have a look at how to use prepared statements too. Your current code risks SQL injection.

Comment: Calling `echo` within a function is what it's called a side-effect. A function at its best should only accept an input and give back one value of a certain type via `return`. Each program must at some point issue side-effect, yet it is key how to handle them. When you call `echo $insert . vars()`, the function vars is interpreted first, hence why you see its output in the beginning. Only then you you echo, but only the content of echo $insert. The response of vars() is void and it will be casted to an empty string `""`.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply append to a string and return it from the function:

```
$format = '("%s", "%s", "%s")';
$values = "";

    if(isset(${"doc" . $x})){
        $values .= sprintf($format, $id, $event_id, ${"doc" . $x});
    }

return $values;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have confused *output*, in the sense of *data displayed on screen or returned to the web browser*; with a function's *result*, the value it *returns to the code that called it*.

Compare these manual pages:

- [echo](http://php.net/echo): Output one or more strings.
- [return](http://php.net/return) / [Returning values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php): Ends execution of the current function, and returns a value to the calling code.

Your `vars()` function *calculates a value for use elsewhere in the code*; it should not be *outputting* that value, but *returning* it for use in whatever way you want.